# Button to make text in the div bolded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new with coding, so bear with me. I've got a button on a page that, if I press on it, should make the specific text bold.

But for some reason it doesn't work and I have no clue why..

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="boldtext();" />
<br />
<div id="text">This is some text</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function boldtext () {
document.getElementById('text').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```

My problem is when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It should work. Have you put the JS after the HTML? Or do you load/declare it inside the `<head>` tag?

Comment: This will work. http://jsbin.com/EYutOfa/2 . It is probabaly the order of your HTML and JS. Make sure the JS comes after the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the JavaScript code in `<head>` tag.
Your code is working. See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/jCgEL/)**

[image]

Comment: Why it should be in head? (**this specific one**) http://jsbin.com/iFisUwE/1/edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The concept is that if you are using pure JavaScript, the JS code should be written before the `HTML` code. As page is read/compiled by browser from top to bottom, so the HTML wont find the JS code if it is written after it. So always write pure JS before making a call to it.

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj ok have you tested my test-case?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, it works because the JS code is above the HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest jQuery solution would be

```
function boldtext () {
    $('#text').css('font-weight','bold');
}
```

**OR**

You can make use of `jQuery event` handler.

```
$('input.btn').click(function(){
    $('#text').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to use jQuery you should create an event handler instead of using inline events

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btn" id="your_button" />
<br />
<div id="text">This is some text</div>
```

JS

```
$('#your_button').click(function(){
    $('#text').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

hope you have wrapped the above script inside `<head>`

```
<head>
<script>
function boldtext () {
document.getElementById('text').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: C'mon What's the difference?? The function is called once the button is clicked...

Comment: Here you go, test, download if you want http://jsbin.com/iFisUwE/1/edit Change the positions of the `<script>` wherever you want

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, You just lookup the answer he marked correct and then down vote ok.  he might have error in his remaining code,so I suggested him to try this.

Comment: why should I down vote? I'm just asking what's the difference?

Comment: Code in the head tag will be executed before that in the body, because of the order of page loading.There is no need to put script in the body unless the script actually does something to the body. Most of the time though you can call the same script in the head of the document after the document has loaded to avoid any errors. Really though you can put the javascript wherever you want. Again putting it in the head of your document makes it load faster.